# I get Error when I try to Submit data - Angular

Tags: angular, post, error-handling

Hello I am having a problem when I want to submit my data to Server. This is my code:

Service.ts:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ArticlesService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   createArticle(title: string, body: string, categoryId: number) {
     const postData: Article = { title: title, body: body, categoryId: categoryId};
     const url = 'http://18.192.182.140/api/articles?api_token=9aK4W3D7NpbWwPzJmUOIcyPmyehl0PHZLWP14rzQqKzUPtcFCo0Tn051CvwN';
     return this.http.post(url, postData)
  }
}
```

Model.ts:

```
export interface Article {
  title: string;
  body: string;
  categoryId: number;
}
```

ArticleComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-new-article',
   templateUrl: './new-article.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./new-article.component.css']
})
export class NewArticleComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private articleService: ArticlesService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void { }

   createNewArticle(postData: Article) {
     this.articleService.createArticle(postData.title, postData.body, 
       postData.categoryId).subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
     });;
```

}

Article.html:

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Add New Article</h1>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createNewArticle(postForm.value)">
     <div id="user-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <input type="text" id="body" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_id">Category ID</label>
        <input type="number" id="category_id" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add new Article</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" routerLink="/admin">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I click on "Add new Article" button I get this error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 
'http://18.192.182.140/api/articles?api_token=9aK4W… 
WwPzJmUOIcyPmyehl0PHZLWP14rzQqKzUPtcFCo0Tn051CvwN', ok: false, …}
```

Anyone know how to solve this error I tried to set responseType to "text" but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Set api token with headers

Comment: Do you have control over the server? Are there any server log information that can help you? Are there any (swagger) documentations?

Comment: I don't see an error. The response has code 200 (OK). It should be a 201, but this is coming from the server. Seems to be a problem on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not sending the information you got with the form
Look at this:
https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup

In the component.ts they get the information with the onsubmit(), I cant see something similar in your code, try to add a console.log before the line "this.articleService.createArticle(postData.title, postData.body," to be sure you are sending something